# InflateException: Selector for disabled button

Tags: android, android-layout

I created a gui with a list of buttons.

Some of those buttons may be disabled and should be displayed in a different color, which is why I added this selector (`color/selector_fav_button.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@color/button_favorite_disabled" />
    <item android:color="@color/button_default"/>
</selector>
```

I reference this selector in a style attribute (values/styles.xml):

```
<style name="favButtonStyle">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/primary_text</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/textView_default_textsize_small</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/selector_favorite_button</item><!--Adding this line causes a crash-->
</style>
```

And the style is referenced in my button:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/fav_button_item_height"
    android:text="@{favBtn.displayText}"
    android:enabled="@{favBtn.isEnabled}"
    style="@style/favButtonStyle"
/>
```

Assigning a color like @color/any_color_but_not_a_selector works fine. If I put a comment around the line, which references any selector, everything works again (except of the colors ;) ).

If I run my app without a comment it crashes and leaves a android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class Button

**EDIT:**
The error occures  here:

```
ListitemFavBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), R.layout.listitem_favBtn, parent, false);
```

Answer (score 2):

Selector should be in `res/drawable`.This

```
 <item name="android:background">@color/selector_favorite_button</item>
```

should be

```
<item name="android:background">@drawable/selector_favorite_button</item>
```

selector is not a color resource.

Comment: could be data binding problem